# Delete selected row in Datagridview

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I have a datagridview in which I want to insert a button for removing the selected row. I created without any problems the AddRow Button and, following the same idea, I tried to create the RemoveRow button with the following code:

```
Private Sub Button6_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button6.Click
        DataGridView2.Rows.Remove()
    End Sub
```

When I start debugging I'm having BC30455 error, about not specified argument. What am I doing wrong? I tried to find out here in the forum but I've found only sth about C# and not VB.net
Best regards and thanks all are gonna answer me.

Comment: You may have noticed that the Remove() method expects a DataGridViewRow argument. So, pass the current: `If DataGridView2.CurrentRow IsNot Nothing Then DataGridView2.Rows.Remove(DataGridView2.CurrentRow) End If`. If you have some doubts about the use of a Method/Property/Whatever, put the caret inside that element and press `F1`: it will open the related documentation in the MSDN Docs -- Try to give more meaningful names to your controls.

Comment: Solved using if loop. Thanks a lot!

Comment: There's no such thing as an "if loop" so who knows whether what you did actually makes sense. In the vast majority of cases, you should be binding your data to the grid. In that case, you should be binding it via a `BindingSource`. In that case, you simply call `RemoveCurrent` on the `BindingSource`.

Comment: Whatever you have found for C# applies to VB as well. The principle is exactly the same and the code will be almost exactly the same too.

Comment: Easy answer to this, maintain the data in the backing data source, then it's just a case of refreshing the UI to match, if that's even needed.  I really don't know why people keep getting stuck in trying to do everything in the UI frameworks

Comment: `DataGridView2.Rows.Remove()` Nicola, look at this line of your code. How in the world would you expect the code to know what row you want to remove? Is it the first row? the last row? the current row? all the rows?

Comment: I thought It was set on default on the current row. I'm learning through using VB how programming languages are meant to be used. I apologize to all of you if some of my questions are trivial, but I'm a newbie at all :)